# Closing and Using new instance of window WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I trying to open a window in WPF that contains only an image and operates as a loading window.

I use the loading window in the same way with all my functions. It always works fine the 1st time it is being used, but every instance of the window after that has blank content. Even if I'm just using a label, it also comes up as blank.

I can't understand why there would be a block on the new instances of the windows preceding the 1st one. Here is the code that I use :

```
        private void btnSaveNewProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loading load = new Loading();

        load.Show();

        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();

        da.ExecuteActionQuery(
            "insert into tbl_Project(ClientID,Name,Description,Billable,FixedPrice,Status,BudgetCap,SalesOrder,ProjectSalesOrder,ProjectType)"
            + " values('"
            + Globals.GetClientId(pw.cbxClients.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "','"
            + pw.txtName.Text.ToString() + "','"
            + pw.txtDescription.Text.ToString() + "','"
            + pw.chxBillable.IsChecked.ToString() + "','"
            + pw.chxFixedPrice.IsChecked.ToString() + "','"
            + pw.cbxStatus.SelectedItem.ToString() + "','"
            + pw.numBudget.ContentText.ToString() + "','"
            + pw.numSalesOrder.ContentText.ToString() + "','"
            + pw.txtName.Text.ToString() + " - " + pw.numSalesOrder.ContentText.ToString() + "','"
            + pw.cbxProjectType.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')");

        load.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        MessageBox.Show("New Project Created Successfully", "Create New Project");

        pw.Close();

        btnProject_Click(null, null);
    }
```

Here is my xaml :

```
<Window x:Class="TT.Windows.Loading"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="" Height="100" Width="100" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid>
    <Image Source="/TT;component/Resources/Sidebar-Search.ico" Height="75" Width="75" />
</Grid>
```

All my click events that need to do DB calls has the same structure as this function : create a load window, show it, do the work and then close it.

The image that I use is set to resource build action.

Advise would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please format / fix your C# code and at least provide the Event that you are doing this code.. it's a bit sloppy, what is the  current window..?? you need to assign the current window.. this.something.Hide() for example.. please clean up your code or provide more code.. for an example look at this posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11359572/how-do-i-return-to-a-window-after-opening-a-second

Comment: Sounds like you're not giving the Dispatcher the time it requires to render everything. What happens if you [DO THE WORK HERE] does nothing?

Comment: My guess is that a lock is somehow being held on the image file.

Comment: Just tried exactly what you are doing and it works fine, strange??
What is the `BuildAction` on your icon?